# how to get Json nested properties to primary one

Tags: c#, json, serialization, nested-attributes

I have below scenario:

This is my class structure :

```
public class User
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Likes> Likes { get; set; }

}

public class Likes
{

    public string Sport { get; set; }

    public string Music { get; set; }

    public string Food { get; set; }

    public string Place { get; set; }


}
```

When I serialize object of User class then it will generate the below json string :

```
{"FirstName":"Naresh",
 "LastName":"Parmar",
 "Likes": [{"Sport":"Cricket",
            "Music":"Classic",
            "Food":"Gujarati",
             "Place":"India"}]
}
```

I want to generate above json string like below:

```
{"FirstName":"Naresh",
 "LastName":"Parmar",
 "Sport":"Cricket",
 "Music":"Classic",
 "Food":"Gujarati",
 "Place":"India"
}
```

I want the nested properties as primary one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

**EDIT:**

```
 {"FirstName":"Naresh",
  "LastName":"Parmar",
  "Sport":"Cricket,Chess,Football",
  "Music":"Classic",
  "Food":"Gujarati",
  "Place":"India"
  }
```

Comment: But what if Likes member contains more than one object (since it's a collection...)? You'll have a problem since according to your request you'll have the same property more than once.

Comment: Hello Felix, Please check EDIT part.

Comment: Hello, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not only limited to Likes objects I'd suggest using dynamic objects. So the User class I propose is as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public dynamic Details { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Details = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    public void AddSingleDetail(string key, string value)
    {
        var dict = this.Details as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key] += "," + value;
        }
        else
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddDetails(object detailsObject)
    {
        var type = detailsObject.GetType();
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            AddSingleDetail(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(detailsObject).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it for adding single proerpties or adding an object as a whole. I used reflection to get all the property name and values and add them to the user details.

Sample usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var user1 = new User() { FirstName = "Homer", LastName = "Simpson" };
    user1.AddSingleDetail("Sport", "Bowling");
    user1.AddSingleDetail("Sport", "Sleeping");
    user1.AddSingleDetail("Food", "Donut");
    user1.AddSingleDetail("Music", "Rock");
    string flattenedHomer1 = ConvertUserToFlattenedJson(user1);

    var user2 = new User() { FirstName = "Homer", LastName = "Simpson" };
    var likes1 = new Likes() { Food = "Donut", Music = "Rock", Place = "Springfield", Sport = "Bowling" };
    var likes2 = new Likes() { Food = "Steaks", Music = "Metal", Place = "Evergreen Terrace", Sport = "Sleeping" };
    var proStuff = new ProfessionalStuff() { Title = "Boss" };
    user2.AddDetails(likes1);
    user2.AddDetails(likes2);
    user2.AddDetails(proStuff);
    string flattenedHomer2 = ConvertUserToFlattenedJson(user2);
}
```

And the method performing the JSON conversion is:

```
public static string ConvertUserToFlattenedJson(User u)
{
    dynamic flatUser = new ExpandoObject();
    flatUser.FirstName = u.FirstName;
    flatUser.LastName = u.LastName;
    var dict = u.Details as IDictionary<string, Object>;
    foreach (var like in dict)
    {
        ((IDictionary<string, Object>)flatUser)[like.Key] = like.Value;
    }

    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flatUser);
    return json;
}
```

In my sample above user2 is converted to the following JSON string which I believe is what you are looking for:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Homer",
  "LastName": "Simpson",
  "Sport": "Bowling,Sleeping",
  "Music": "Rock,Metal",
  "Food": "Donut,Steaks",
  "Place": "Springfield,Evergreen Terrace",
  "Title": "Boss"
}
```

While concatenating strings you can check for null or duplicate values. I didn't handle that part.

For the sake of completeness, here's the ProfessionalStuff class I made up:

```
public class ProfessionalStuff
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In place of `.First()` there is option of using `.Single()` then if not exactly one will fall over. Or `.SingleOrDefault()` which will fall over if `>1`

Comment: I went with that one at first but it doesn't compile: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'" It's looking for a condition : "Returns the first element in a sequence that satisfies a specified condition". taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking rubbish!

Comment: Thanks Volkan, I got your point.. Its very useful. But If I have dynamic user properties. Like, one clients need above one, another one need some professional details. And I want to prepare one generic solutions for that. Is it possible !?

Comment: @NareshParmar - I updated my answer to reflect your update in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad practice, since the code i'll post bellow doesn't have great maintainability, however if that's what you looking for, you can use this. Another class that have the format that you'd like, and have a method that adds a list of likes to the format you've required. That the class you should serialize to JSON:

```
    class NestedUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Sport { get; set; }

        public string Music { get; set; }

        public string Food { get; set; }

        public string Place { get; set; }

        public void AddLikes(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Likes> likes)
        {
            foreach (Likes like in likes)
            {
                Sport += like.Sport + ",";
                Music += like.Music + ",";
                Food += like.Food + ",";
                Place += like.Place + ",";
            }

            if (Sport != string.Empty)
            {
                Sport = Sport.Substring(0, Sport.Length - 1);
            }
            if (Music != string.Empty)
            {
                Music = Music.Substring(0, Music.Length - 1);
            }
            if (Food != string.Empty)
            {
                Food = Food.Substring(0, Food.Length - 1);
            }
            if (Place != string.Empty)
            {
                Place = Place.Substring(0, Place.Length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```